# Test to prevent java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, testing, jvm, classloader

I've just fixed a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` at server boot time in my Scala code caused by incompatible libraries. Is there a way to write a test to exclude such errors by, e.g., forcing all classes in the class path to load?

Comment: How do incompatible libraries cause a `NoClassDefFoundError`? I can understand if it was a `MethodNotFoundError` since different class versions can overwrite each other on the classpath.

Comment: I think the class causing that error was removed in later versions of the library, but old code in another library depends on it.

Comment: That makes sense. If you can get ahold of the older library, you could relocate it using the shade plugin in your build script. That way you can use 2 versions of the same library.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be solved by a unit test since a unit test possibly runs against a different classpath. The best you can do is to make your build fail in case of any version conflict. It's possible with any build tool.